# Unable to install linux headers 5.10.0-24-cloud-amd64

Tags: drivers, apt, linux-headers

I am trying to install linux headers on a fresh machine (google cloud) using the standard command

```
sudo apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

My uname -r version is 5.10.0-24-cloud-amd64, but when I try to install it I run into the same error

```
E: Package 'linux-headers-5.10.0-24-cloud-amd64' has no installation candidate
```

I was able to install these headers only a few hours ago (August 23nd 2023) on another fresh instance, but now it suddenly doesn't work. I am also listing the available versions using

```
apt-cache search linux-headers
```

but I'm not able to find the designated install (I get 5.10.0-20,22,25 but not 24). My apt version is apt 2.2.4 (amd64) on both machines.

Comment: You haven't provided any OS/release, but 5.10 is a Debian kernel and not a Ubuntu kernel.  A look online and I see only non-Ubuntu sources for it  (Debian *bullseye* mostly).

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official *flavors* of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.